# Microsoft Azure mobile SDK custom provider login IOS

Tags: swift, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I have followed [this tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) to implement a login with custom provider on an Azure mobile app. The backend works perfectly but when I try to login to my new custom controller I'm not able to do it. It's possible to implement it with Xamarin and also with java Android but is no way to do it with Objective C or Swift.

The object `MSClient` on Microsoft Azure mobile SDK [only has two login implementations.](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-services/iOS/v3/Classes/MSClient.html)

I have tried both but without luck, the callback always returns an empty client.
I also have tried to store the token created by own API use it for login call but without luck again.

Here is my Swift code:

```
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://myApp.azurewebsites.net")
    client.login(withProvider: "custom", urlScheme: "myApp", parameters: ["username": "pau", "password": "123456"], controller: self, animated: true) {user, error in
        print("USER", user)
        print("ERROR", error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution, it's really easy but the msclient documentation is not clear enough. You just need to pass whatever you need (i.e: username,password) as dictionary in token parameter.

```
        Client.msClient.login(withProvider: "auth", token: params, completion: {user, error in
            print("USER", user)
            print("ERROR", error)
            print("USER ID", user?.userId)
            print("TOKEN", user?.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken)

            if let user: MSUser = user {
                guard let username: String = user.userId else { return }
                guard let token: String = user.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken else { return }
                Client.username = username
                Client.msClient.currentUser = user
                completion(true)
            }else {
                completion(false)
            }
        })
```